# redirect in function of ip address (in function of the country)

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm trying to redirect the visitors of a website in function of their ip address
I tried following code which works fine , but since I have some carousels and other stuff, the page refrehes at every call from for example the carrousel ( the caroussel loads dynamicly it's pictures)
That's because I've put the code in the onClientLoad.
Is there a way to put it in for example the beforepageload ?

How?

I guess it will only load once then ?

My code :

```
<xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[jQuery.getJSON('http://freegeoip.net/json/', function(location) {
// If the visitor is browsing from ...
if (location.country_code == 'BE') {
// normally I put my website here which contains the carrousel etc
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.be';
}
if (location.country_code == 'FR') {
// normally I also put a another website here which contains a carrousel etc
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.fr';
}
});]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

**EDIT**

By "redirect in function of ip address" I mean in fact in function of the country the visitor is visiting the website from.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Server Side JS in the beforePageLoad event.

Get the IP address with this technique http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/xpages-cgi-variables.htm

And then use this to redirect:

facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect("www.tlcc.com");

Howard

Comment: By "redirect in function of ip address" I mean in fact in function of the country the visitor is visiting the website from.